# Error including <vector> in Netbeans (C++)

Tags: c++, netbeans, vector, cygwin

This is odd. I'm getting errors for including `<vector>`: (edit: works fine with `<list>` but I don't want to forsake vectors)

```
g++.exe    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o main.cpp
                 from MemoryScanner.h:11,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_bvector.h: In member function `void std::vector<bool, _Alloc>::_M_insert_range(std::_Bit_iterator, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag)':
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/vector:72,
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_bvector.h:522: error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_bvector.h: In member function `void std::vector<bool, _Alloc>::_M_fill_insert(std::_Bit_iterator, size_t, bool)':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/stl_bvector.h:823: error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token
                 from MemoryScanner.h:11,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/vector.tcc: In member function `void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename _Alloc::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, size_t, const _Tp&)':
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/vector:75,
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/vector.tcc:307: error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/vector.tcc: In member function `void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename _Alloc::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag)':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/vector.tcc:384: error: expected unqualified-id before '(' tokenmake[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/k/Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/MemScan'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/k/Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/MemScan'

make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

The lines referenced:

```
#include "MemoryScanner.h" // main.cpp:10

#include <vector> // MemoryScanner.h:12
```

Edit:

**MemoryScanner.h**

```
#ifndef MEMORYSCANNER_H
#define MEMORYSCANNER_H

#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct memblock {
    int address;
    int value;
};

class MemoryScanner {
private:
    HANDLE _hProc;
    vector<memblock> _addresses;
public:
    MemoryScanner(HANDLE hProc);
    MemoryScanner(const MemoryScanner& orig);
    void scan(int value);
    void display();
    virtual ~MemoryScanner();
};

#endif  /* MEMORYSCANNER_H */
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "MemoryScanner.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(0, "Calculator");

    if (hWnd == 0) {
        cout << "Could not retrieve window handler" << endl;
    } else {
        DWORD pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
        HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pid);

        if (!hProc) {
            cout << "Could not open process" << endl;
        } else {
            MemoryScanner* scanner = new MemoryScanner(hProc);

            int value;
            cout << "Enter value: ";
            cin >> dec >> value;
            scanner->scan(value);
            scanner->display();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can we see how you use vector in your code?

Comment: post some code from MemoryScanner.h

Comment: Can we have the rest of the compiler error?

Comment: @Gio Borje : why so many compiler options? it looks your problem is those...not in the code itself :-s

Comment: What's wrong with the compiler options? I just got Netbeans today and followed a tutorial to use cygwin as the compiler for it.

Comment: @Gio : got Netbeans today? You mean, this is your first program using Netbeans? If so, have you tested it by writing some simple 6 lines program, *#including <vector>* especially?

Comment: `#include vector` works fine on any blank project. Threw it in some header files, still works fine.

Comment: @Gio : black project is different; blank projects don't instantiate class templates. Have you tried using vector in a simple project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/Facepalm. I just needed to remove `#include <windows.h>` from `main.cpp` because it's already included in `MemoryScanner.h`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *MemoryScanner.h* has defined a macro that happens to match a name that the *vector* header uses. Have you looked at what those lines of code in *vector* and *stl_bvector.h* contain?

I try to include system headers and external library headers before I include project-specific headers so that if a problem arises, the compiler is more likely to point at a file that I have the power to change.